# Multiprocessing of two for loops

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, physics, python-2.x

I'm struggling with the implementation of an algorithm in python (2.7) to parallelize the computation of a physics problem. There's a parameter space over two variables (let's say a and b) over which I would like to run my written program f(a,b) which returns two other variables c and d.

Up to now, I worked with two `for`-loops over a and b to calculate two arrays for c and d which are then saved as txt documents. Since the parameter space is relatively large and each calculation of a point f(a,b) in it takes relatively long, it would be great to use all of my 8 CPU cores for the parameter space scan.

I've read about multithreading and multiprocessing and it seems that multiprocessing is what I'm searching for. Do you know of a good code example for this application or resources to learn about the basics of multiprocessing for my rather simple application?

Comment: In Python, you won't be able to use all your CPU cores with multithreading. You will need multiprocessing.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I'll correct that in my question.

Comment: As of 1-01-2020, there is no more support for Python 2.x versions. Consider upgrading to Python 3.x

Comment: I know, I have to use deprecated packages which only work on python 2

Comment: @JacobK: stackoverflow still supports Python 2. `;¬)`

Comment: Carlo: [Easy Concurrency in Python](http://pljung.de/posts/easy-concurrency-in-python/?utm_source=Iterable&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=the-overflow-newsletter&utm_content=10-30-19) and [An introduction to parallel programming using Python's multiprocessing module](https://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_multiprocessing.html).

Comment: @martineau thank you very much for correcting my question and the useful links!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how you might use multiprocessing with a simple function that takes two arguments and returns a tuple of two numbers, and a parameter space over which you want to do the calculation:

```
from itertools import product
from multiprocessing import Pool
import numpy as np

def f(a, b):
    c = a + b
    d = a * b
    return (c, d)

a_vals = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
b_vals = [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]

na = len(a_vals)
nb = len(b_vals)

p = Pool(8)  # <== maximum number of simultaneous worker processes

answers = np.array(p.starmap(f, product(a_vals, b_vals))).reshape(na, nb, 2)

c_vals = answers[:,:,0]
d_vals = answers[:,:,1]
```

This gives the following:

```
>>> c_vals
array([[11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18],
       [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
       [14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22],
       [16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]])

>>> d_vals
array([[ 10,  11,  12,  13,  14,  15,  16,  17],
       [ 20,  22,  24,  26,  28,  30,  32,  34],
       [ 30,  33,  36,  39,  42,  45,  48,  51],
       [ 40,  44,  48,  52,  56,  60,  64,  68],
       [ 50,  55,  60,  65,  70,  75,  80,  85],
       [ 60,  66,  72,  78,  84,  90,  96, 102]])
```

The `p.starmap` returns a list of 2-tuples, from which the c and d values are then extracted.

This assumes that you will do your file I/O in the main program after getting back all the results.

---

**Addendum**:

If `p.starmap` is unavailable (Python 2), then instead you can change your function to take a single input (a 2-element tuple):

```
def f(inputs):
    a, b = inputs
    # ... etc as before ...
```

and then use `p.map` in place of `p.starmap` in the above code.

If it is not convenient to change the function (e.g. it is also called from elsewhere), then you can of course write a wrapper function:

```
def f_wrap(inputs):
    a, b = inputs
    return f(a, b)
```

and call that instead.

Comment: Well, I guess I was a bit too fast: p.starmap worked for me when I tested it using python 3. Can you think of a solution without that starmap feature?

Comment: @CarloTasillo You could use `p.map` instead and then the function takes a single argument (a 2-element tuple). Just unpack this into `a, b` at the start of the function.

Comment: @CarloTasillo Added an addendum to the answer now.

Comment: Thank you very much, now everything works just as wanted!